# Arranging images, arrows, text and similar for research presentation

Tags: software-recommendation, illustration, presentation-design, comics

I am going to prepare presentation slides for a research presentation. Below I am showing an example of type of images people generally include in such presentations. The presentation has been prepared in Latex which I know to use. But, the image includes many discrete components, e.g., faces, arrows, and text, stitched together.

I am not sure which graphic software is best suitable for creation of such a graphic. To clarify, I am **not** planning to create individual “components”. Those I will use ready-made, downloaded from Internet. The problem lies in compiling those together to create a meaningful image as per my needs. Will Gimp be sufficient, or are there easier alternatives?

[image]

Comment: On a sidenote, I recommend that you use a font for the presentation that is better suited for low screen resolutions, such as a sans-serif without stroke variation. The font you are using does not render well on low-resolution projectors.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest one of the following:

- [**TikZ**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) is a LaTeX package that enables you to draw diagrams directly from LaTeX source code. The main advantage is that the text is rendered by LaTeX and you can typset formulas as in LaTeX. Thus you do not have to hassle with other ways to render formulas and your text matches your main text in font and size. The main disadvantages are that it has a slow learning curve and is not WYSIWYG. Due to the latter, I would not recommend it to draw something like your faces, should you have the need one day (but you can still import those with TikZ).
- [**Inkscape**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inkscape) is a free vector graphics program. It allows you to embed other graphics and is thus suitable for such jobs as connecting two existing images with arrows. It has tools like a formula renderer and allows exporting images in a way that allows for the text to be rendered by TeX. It is WYSIWYG and thus more suitable for drawing something like your faces. It’s SVG- and thus XML-based and thus you can directly work with the files on a source basis and reasonably version it. Finally, you can embed other images as links, if you want to. On the downside, it also has a slow learning curve and it does not as nicely integrate into TeX as TikZ (not that it integrates badly).

I recommend against using any pixel-based software like GIMP, as the result does not optimally scale, which is particularly visible on low resolutions, which projectors tend to have. In particular text and thin lines suffer when rescaled.

Comment: Yes, indeed I want to stitch parts of the image, e.g. faces, together to form a complete image for illustration.

Comment: Edited. Does it make more sense now?